# Detailed explanation on how to know what the output will be when slicing and reversing a string in Python

Tags: python, string, slice

```
a="qwerty"
```

And I want the output to be "tre". But whenever I try doing

```
print(a[2:5:-1])
print(a[-4:-1:-1])
print(a[2:-1:-1])
print(a[-4:5:-1])
```

It all gives me blank spaces. But when I try

```
print(a[-2:-5:-1])
```

It magically outputs what I need.

So here's the question: Why didn't it work all those time, but did when I sliced it like this [-2:-5:-1]? Even though, as I think, I sliced and reversed the same piece of string. Explanation in details is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of the way `stepping` works in python. When you type `my_list[start:end:step]` python will interpret this as follows:

start from `start` index to `end` index value (not including `end` index itself) and each step should be `step` value.

For example consider the example below:

```
my_str = 'abcdefghijk'

print(my_str[2:7:2])
```

This code will give you `ceg` as output. Why? Because it moves from index number 2 to 7 not including 7 index itself. So it is 'cdefg'. Then get them with 2 steps meaning first `c` then increase the index by 2 (index=4) so gets to `e` (skips the `d` value).

But you need to know how reverse index works with stepping that I explained below.

#### Reverse stepping

What happens if the `stepping` value is negative. It starts from the `start` and move to the `end` number by -1 stepping value meaning that it moves backwards step by step.

But notice that it moves backwards to reach the `end` index. So the `start` value should be after the `end` in the list because it wants to move backwards from the `start` index to the `end` index. ([..., `end`, ...<---..., `start`, ...])

### The reason of the output you asked

So when you typed `print(a[-4:-1:-1])` python starts from -4 and each time moves one step backward to reach index -1 but it never happens as index -1 is after index number -4 and not before that. So python can't get the string so it returns -1. Same happens for the other examples.

But when you typed `print(a[-2:-5:-1])` python starts from index -2 and move backwards step by step (-2 -> -3 -> -4) so it gets to index -5 and it stops and returns the value.

If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Absolutely no questions. The best explanation I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

As listed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

`s[i:j:k]` slice of `s` from `i` to `j` with step `k`

With the resulting list being: `[s[i], s[i+k], ..., s[j]`